# AlarmManager after 12pm

Tags: android, calendar, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to send local push-notifications. For that I defined an AlarmManager, that should make a push nontification sent one second later. 
That works fine... until 12pm. It is now two days in a row, that the app doesn't work after 12pm, but fine before.

Here is the definition of the AlarmManager:

```
public void click(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Push.class);

    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService
                (ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                calendar.getTimeInMillis()+1000, pendingIntent);

    Log.d("Push", "started");
}
```

And that is the BroadcastReceiver's onReceive():

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    Log.d("Push", "done");
    [...]
}
```

Do you have an idea why it always fails? I suppose it is the calendar, but I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any issues in the code here. If you havent solved the problem yet, then please post more detailed information or code, so we can identify the problem.

You can also try to solve the problem with the Handler class.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)

The Android Documentation also recommends this for.

> Note: for timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found my mistake. That were two diffrent mistakes (unfortunately two times made around 12pm)